# php - Get array of dates in same week as a $date

Tags: php

Sorry for my bad english.

As said in the title , i would to get array of dates in same week(between monday to friday) as a $date

exemple : if $date = `2015-05-05` => i would to have

array that contain : `2015-05-04 , 2015-05-05 ,2015-05-06 2015-05-07, 2015-05-08`

Comment: We are not a code writing service. Show us your attempts and ask a real question.

Comment: Show your efforts. What you have tried so far

Comment: i'm just a student , and i don't know how to do it

Comment: @user3499993 We neither can read nor learn for you. You have to learn -> http://php.net/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yet another solution

```
 $my_date = "2012-10-18"; 
 $week = date("W", strtotime($my_date)); // get week
 $y =    date("Y", strtotime($my_date)); // get year
 echo $first_date =  date('d-m-Y',strtotime($y."W".$week)); //first date 
 echo $second_date = date("d-m-Y",strtotime("+1 day", strtotime($first_date)));
```

you can loop  or add `+1` to previous date and so on..

Answer (score 3):

Just change the date strings of "2015-05-05" to your desired date.

```
$day_of_week = date('N', strtotime('2015-05-05'));

$given_date = strtotime("05-05-2015");

$first_of_week =  date('Y-m-d', strtotime("- {$day_of_week} day", $given_date));

$first_of_week = strtotime($first_of_week);

for($i=0 ;$i<=7; $i++) {
    $week_array[] = date('Y-m-d', strtotime("+ {$i} day", $first_of_week));
}

print_r($week_array);
```

Answer (score 1):

[Date](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) and [strtotime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) are your friends on this:

```
$myDate = "2015-05-05";

echo date("Y-m-d", strtotime('monday this week', strtotime($myDate)))."\n";
echo date("Y-m-d", strtotime('tuesday this week', strtotime($myDate)))."\n";
echo date("Y-m-d", strtotime('wednesday this week', strtotime($myDate)))."\n";
echo date("Y-m-d", strtotime('thursday this week', strtotime($myDate)))."\n";
echo date("Y-m-d", strtotime('friday this week', strtotime($myDate)))."\n";
```

Output:

```
2015-04-05
2015-05-05
2015-06-05
2015-07-05
2015-08-05
```

Demo:

http://ideone.com/hEem8k

Comment: thank you , it give days of the current week , i need now to now how to have the week of the $date

Comment: Change `this week` for the date you want.

Comment: @PedroLobito You already know what I think right now :). The only thing which I'm curious about now is: Where do you see effort and work in this question, in which word/sentence ?

Comment: I found that : $week = (int)date('W', $date); to get the week number ; i tryed this :  echo date("d m Y", strtotime('monday '.$week));  but it gives me always : 01 01 1970

Comment: thank you , @Rizier123 : if you could help me i would be very grateful otherwise don't write anything

Comment: @user3499993 I can write whenever I want. I think this is interesting for you: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/3933332

Comment: @Rizier123 this one was more of a challenge for me, but you're 100% right, the OP didn't show any effort or work. also, he has an history of low quality questions.

Answer (score 0):

This function will return all dates of current week starting from `monday` to `sunday`

**[See Working Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/3c20937e012c1e4e9ddf4681d876bd897fae5e20)**

```
function GetCurrentWeekDates()
{
    if (date('D') != 'Mon') {
        $startdate = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('last Monday'));
    } else {
        $startdate = date('Y-m-d');
    }

//always next saturday
    if (date('D') != 'Sat') {
        $enddate = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('next Saturday'));
    } else {
        $enddate = date('Y-m-d');
    }

    $DateArray = array();
    $timestamp = strtotime($startdate);
    while ($startdate <= $enddate) {
        $startdate = date('Y-m-d', $timestamp);
        $DateArray[] = $startdate;
        $timestamp = strtotime('+1 days', strtotime($startdate));
    }
    return $DateArray;
}
print_r(GetCurrentWeekDates());
```

Comment: thank you but i want to have weekdates from $dates , could i only change : date('D') by date('D', $date)